# Python argparse: type conversion of a list of default arguments

Tags: python, list, default, argparse

I'm writing a tool with argparse that'll take a list of source directories from the command line and process all the files in them. Ultimately, when parse_args is called, each directory is scanned for files to process, and the list of files is put into the `files` attribute off the returned namespace.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--sources'
    , dest = 'files'
    , default = 'results/e1653a3'
    , nargs = '*'
    , metavar = 'SOURCE'
    , action = ConcatAction
    , type = FileList
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here, the `FileList` function takes a directory name and returns a list of files. `ConcatAction` is an action which flattens a list of lists. The result is that I can call my tool like `tool.py -s dir1 dir2`, and `args.files` contains all the files in both directories.

By default, I want it to scan multiple directories; however, passing a list to the defaults:

```
, default = ['dir1', 'dir2']
```

Sidesteps the type conversion system of argparse, so `FileList()` is never called, and `args.files` contains the list `['dir1', 'dir2']`, and not the scanned files. If I try

```
, default = 'dir1 dir2'
```

Then a single call to `FileList('dir1 dir2')` is made instead of the two calls `FileList('dir1')` `FileList('dir2')`

I know I can just process the source directories outside of argparse to get the functionality I want, but is there anyway to get argparse to perform type conversion on a list of default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, a string default is passed through the type function, while all other defaults are simply assigned to the attribute (unchanged).  I think the solution is to build the exact file list that you want to see in the Namespace in the default case.

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--sources'
    , dest = 'files'
    , default = [FileList('dir1'), FileList('dir2')] # exact file list
    , nargs = '*'
    , metavar = 'SOURCE'
    , action = ConcatAction
    , type = FileList
)
```

I'll let you worry about applying that flattening action.

Or you could initialize a Namespace with the desired file list.  In this case the `default` is ignored.

```
ns = argparse.NameSpace(files = [FileList('dir1'), FileList('dir2')])
# or
ns = argparse.NameSpace(files = ['dir1/file1','dir1/file2','dir2/file1',...])
parser.parse_args(sys.argv, namespace=ns)
```

Comment: Forgot to accept this. This is the solution I ended up going with, though I don't like that it calls FileList for the default values regardless of whether it uses the defaults or not. Good enough for my uses, I suppose.